# Unable to test data in Angular Material Data Table: TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of null

Tags: angular-material, angular-test, angular-material-table

I am writing unit test cases for Angular material table. Here's the template code snippet:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

  <!-- Edit/Delete -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
      <div class="mat-table-header">Action</div>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let type">
      <div class="row-action">
        <button class="btn--delete" mat-icon-button aria-label="delete button" (click)="openDeleteDialog(type)">
          <span class="icon-delete"></span>
        </button>

        <button class="btn--edit" mat-icon-button aria-label="edit button"
          (click)="openAddOrEditDialog(category.TYPE, type)">
          <span class="icon-edit"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Type Name -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="avtName">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="mat-table-header">Type</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let type">{{ type.avtName }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let type; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
```

I am testing the `openAddOrEditDialog` which opens a `MatDialog`. I have inserted 2 records into the data table. When I try to test the clicking of the edit button by using `fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(".btn--edit"))`, I always get `null`, meaning the records didn't get rendered in the data table, but, when I query the table using `fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("table"))`, I can see the records in the `console.log(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("table")))`.

Where am I going wrong?

Here's my test case:

```
it(`some description`, () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(notificationService, "notifySuccess");
  const editBtn: HTMLElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(".btn--edit"))
    .nativeElement;

  editBtn.click();

  expect(spy).toBeCalledWith("Type was successfully updated");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer.

We can not use `fixture.debugElement.query` for Angular Material Data Table, instead it works with `fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector`.

It is suggested in https://medium.com/@penghuili/angular-unit-test-cant-query-material-table-e2c25abc4937